# Push Notification gets changed after more notification comes in Notification Drawer

Tags: android, notifications

I'm facing one small issue in Notification Building..
When there is no notification other than my apps notification it works fine(as shown in below)..
[image]

But when any notification comes on Notification Drawer it get changed to(as shown in below)..
[image]

I don't know what exactly the problem is.. can anybody tell me what should I do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the way android notification system works. You can expand yourself the notification using 2 fingers to pull and expand the notification (or one, after 4.1.2 was released)

[Here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/10/09/new-in-android-4-1-2-expandingcollapsing-notifications-with-one-finger-video/) there is a video about that feature